# Fluid design images do not scale correctly

Tags: css, html, fluid-layout

I have an issue with my fluid design. Here is my test site - www.lync-star.com

You will notice that when the browser window is shrunk, all the images scale correctly.

However, when the screen gets smaller (approx i phone size 360 x 640), the images are very small in comparison to the text and headings (for example the top image)

How can I get around this? do I need to use media queries in order to load another image that is a lot larger?

I hope the above makes sense?

Best,
p

Answer (score 0):

It's the proportions of the images. If your image is ~800x270 and it has a `max-width` of `100%` then it will retain those proportions as the width of the image shrinks. You either need to use media queries to reduce the text size as the page gets smaller, or you need to load an image with different proprortions.

In any case, this is how you'd do it

```
media(min-width: 768px) // Obviously, change 768 to whatever you desire
{
    // Any rules applied inside of this media(){} block will be 
    // applied on browser windows wider than 767px
    div#header_img 
    {
        background-image: url('path/to/img.png'); // Normal header image
    }
}

media(max-width: 767px)
{
    div#header_img
    {
        background-image: url('path/to/img.png'); // Alternative image, perhaps taller?
    }
}
```

The same principle could be applied to the text size as well. Have a read about media queries [here](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

You could also play around with the [`background-size`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp) and try and make it so that the image stays the same size, but less of it is visible as the `div` it is the background of shrinks.